# VS2015: test status icon missing just above method signature

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, test-explorer

Currently when I run my tests, I don't get to see the 'icon' just above the test method signature.

The provided screenshot shows the icon I'm talking about:

[image: test explorer icon]

Does anyone know on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you enabled the "Show Test Status" option in CodeLens.

You can find it under:

Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens -> "Show Test Status"